# Overriding implementation with ZF2 service manager

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Suppose in my Zf2 application I have a class `A` that is retrieved via service manager

```
'service_manager' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'A' => 'A'
    ]
]
```

If, everytime I am retrieving class `A`, I want instead to return a decorator `B` of `A`, I could use a delegator factory.

What now if I would like to decorate in this way all the classes implementing an interface `I`, whenever I retrieve them from the service manager? Initializers do not seem to be helping here since they can not substitute the implementation retrieved from the service manager.

Is there a way to do this? Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: Abstract factory? You can check if the service implements `I` in the `canCreateServiceWithName` function.

Comment: I can not change how A is declared in the service manager declaration. I need to modify only the class returned by the service manager when retrieving the `A` class

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom plugin manager which is responsible for creating services of type `I`.

This would allow you to register custom factories for each service (or abstract factory) and still decorate the original service registered with the service manager.

The below configuration might help explain.

```
return [
    'service_manager' => [
        'invokables' => [
            'A' => 'A',
            'B' => 'B',
        ]
    ],
    'foo_plugin_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'B' => 'FactoryB'
        ],
        'abstract_factories' => [
            'AbstractFactoryThatDecoratesAll',
        ]
    ],
];
```

The issue with this approach is that you would need to update any calls to

```
$serviceManager->get('A')
```

with

```
$serviceManager->get('FooPluginManager')->get('A')
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I think I can't do that. I'm working with an external library that is using directly the service manager, so I can't introduce a plugin manager into play

Comment: @marcosh Is there any reason why you can't just register the decorator for each service?

Comment: Because I'm working on a module that could be used by somebody else, so I don't know which service exactly I will have to decorate. I would like to expose just the interface, and use that to perform the decoration